# Ionic 4 - Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Recently I started facing this error in console after `--prod` build:

`Could not find cordova.js script tag. Plugin loading may fail`

Some of plugins throw errors and warnings when they'd been called (e.g. AppVersion). I created a new Ionic 4 project and it shows this error as well.

Build **without** `--prod` flag works correctly!

It's **android** only.

What I attempted and it didn't help:

- reinstalling everything by `ionic repair`
- creating new projects from scratch and build
- downgrade / update cordova-android versions

My `ionic info` output:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (/Users/developer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.8.1) : 0.6.0
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.3

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/developer/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.2
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.3 Build version 10G8
```

### Temporary solution:

Then I've found what causes it - I just changed following keys in `angular.json` for production configuration:

- "optimization": false,
- "outputHashing": "none",

Now it works, but because of it the final bundle isn't being compressed.

### The question:

Does anyone understand what causes this error? What does it depend on?

Comment: Not sure is this helpful or not. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-not-find-cordova-js-script-tag-plugin-loading-may-fail/144927/16

Comment: I am also searching for same :(

Comment: I have this error, did you solve ?
I see that It's only happend on mac platform